# setClipboardString from System.Clipboard is not working

Tags: haskell, clipboard

`setClipboardString` and `modifyClipboardString` are not changing clipboard for me (reading clipboard is fine). I am trying it on KDE (Kubuntu 16.04).

Is there something special required to make it work or is there some other way of accessing clipboard?

Comment: More info: I have installed the only dependency listed on hackage (`libxrandr-dev`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried another library - [HClip](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Hclip-3.0.0.4/docs/System-Hclip.html) (with `xclip`) and its `setClipboard` is working as intended.

PS: I am using CopyQ and IDEA which may be interfering with clipboard operations.